# How to use Cordova Geolocation with OpenWeatherMap in Ionic?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova, openweathermap

I have an Ionic project connected to the OpenWeatherMap API, and I would like to use the Cordova plugin for geolocation; I tried to connect them, and I managed to be geolocalized, but impossible to get an answer from the API ...

However the API was configured correctly since I was able to get data before putting the plugin ...

Here is the code :

controllers.js =>

```
angular.module('weather')
.controller('WeatherCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaGeolocation, $http, OpenWeatherConfig) {
  var posOptions = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: false};
  $cordovaGeolocation
    .getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
    .then(function (position) {
      var lat  = position.coords.latitude;
      var lng = position.coords.longitude;
    }, function(err) {
    });
  $scope.state = false;
  $scope.weatherData = {
    icon: '',
    main: '',
    city: '',
    description: '',
    coord: '',
    temp: ''
  };
  $scope.loadWeather = function(lat, lng) {
    var url = OpenWeatherConfig.searchUrl + 'lat=' + lat + '&lon=' + lng + OpenWeatherConfig.units + OpenWeatherConfig.appid;
    $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
      $scope.weatherData.icon = OpenWeatherConfig.imgUrl + data.weather[0].icon + '.png';
      $scope.weatherData.main = data.weather[0].main;
      $scope.weatherData.city = data.name;
      $scope.weatherData.description = data.weather[0].description;
      $scope.weatherData.coord = data.coord;
      $scope.weatherData.temp = data.main.temp;
      $scope.state = true;
    });
  };
});
```

weather.html =>

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-content overflow-scroll="false" class="weather-home">
    <button class="button button-full button-calm" ng-click="loadWeather()">
      Search
    </button>
    <div ng-if="state" class="forecast">
        <img src="{{weatherData.icon}}" class="icon"/>
        <label class="bigText">{{weatherData.main}}</label>
        <div class="mainText">Town : {{weatherData.city}}</div>
        <div class="mainText">Current conditions : {{weatherData.description}}</div>
        <div class="mainText">Geographical coordinates : {{weatherData.coord}}</div>
        <div class="bigText">{{weatherData.temp}} °C</div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Nothing appears in the Firefox console, and I have only made changes in these files since the API was running ...

Comment: Have u try test the api using rest client. Is it return results?

Comment: Yes, as I said in the question, the API worked before adding the plugin, it worked with the name of the city ... And I just tested it in the plugin Firefox RESTClient, with the coordinates this time, it works too ...

Comment: I found the problem, although the lat & lng variables retrieve geolocation, these values are not passed to the url variable ... I just need to find the changes to make to resolve this problem ...

Comment: Oh..I see. Where do you call scope.loadWeather function. I don't see it in your code.

Comment: I begin my learning of angular and ionic, so I confess to be a little lost ... the whole of my file controllers.js is here, the call to the function $scope.loadWeather is therefore absent, I do not know where and how to integrate it ...

Comment: I found yesterday evening a doc for this here => https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-geolocation/ , but impossible for me to integrate this code with mine

Comment: Oh. There's nothing to worry about. Just learning from mistakes. You can call scope.loadWeather after you get the lat & lng, i mean after success callback in then. Pass lat & lng as parameters. For e.g.: scope.loadWeather(lat, lng).

Comment: Thank you very much, I receive the weather data! Now I only have to adjust some details to match the desired operation and I will post the answer for other users as soon as possible!

Comment: Glad to hear that. You' re welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to "digit" to helping me find the way !

Here is the solution :

controllers.js =>

```
.controller('WeatherCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaGeolocation, $http, OpenWeatherConfig) {
  $scope.state = false;
  $scope.weatherData = {
    icon: '',
    main: '',
    city: '',
    description: '',
    lat:'',
    lon: '',
    temp: ''
  };
  $scope.loadWeather = function() {
    var posOptions = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: false};
    $cordovaGeolocation
    .getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
    .then(function (position) {
      var lat  = position.coords.latitude;
      var lon = position.coords.longitude;

      var url = OpenWeatherConfig.searchUrl + 'lat=' + lat + '&lon=' + lon + OpenWeatherConfig.units + OpenWeatherConfig.appid;
      $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
       $scope.weatherData.icon = OpenWeatherConfig.imgUrl + data.weather[0].icon + '.png';
       $scope.weatherData.main = data.weather[0].main;
       $scope.weatherData.city = data.name;
       $scope.weatherData.description = data.weather[0].description;
       $scope.weatherData.lat = data.coord.lat;
       $scope.weatherData.lon = data.coord.lon;
       $scope.weatherData.temp = data.main.temp;
       $scope.state = true;
      });
    }, function(err) {
    });
  };
});
```

weather.html =>

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-content overflow-scroll="false" class="weather-home">
    <button class="button button-full button-calm" ng-click="loadWeather()">
      Search
    </button>
    <div ng-if="state" class="forecast">
      <img src="{{weatherData.icon}}" class="icon"/>
      <label class="bigText">{{weatherData.main}}</label>
      <div class="mainText">Town : {{weatherData.city}}</div>
      <div class="mainText">Current Conditions : {{weatherData.description}}</div>
      <div class="mainText">Geographical coordinates : {{weatherData.lat}}, {{weatherData.lon}}</div>
      <div class="bigText">{{weatherData.temp}} °C</div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Could you explain what exactly has changed between the non-working and working versions of the code?

Comment: 1/ The code of the question was more wobbly at first, but I have improved a bit in the hours after the post, so I modified the question ...

Comment: 2/ Then "$ scope.loadWeather (lat, lon);" was missing, so the "lat" & "lng" variables would lose their value before the "url" variable would need these values to be used to retrieve the weather data.

Comment: 3/ Then "cordova-plugin-geolocation" was outside the "loadWeather" function, so position recovery, calling and displaying of weather data were done at loading, whereas only the position had to, the rest depends on the ng-click that triggers the "loadWeather" function.

Comment: 4/ There is also the renaming of the variable for longitude, "lng" becomes "lon", because to retrieve the coordinates, the OpenWeatherMap API requires that this variable be named "lon".

Comment: 5/ And for an optimal display, the object "coord" had to leave its place to the 2 variables mentioned above, and this, in 3 places (of which 2 in the controller).